# How to add background image to Wordpress theme's Accelerate

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Hi guys i've been working for this for days and searching the net for help but unluckily I don't find one. Here's my problem, I know that wordpress has a built-in background image when you click the appearance. I also tried editing in the CSS but when I put the code 
`background-image: url(image/3.jpg)` in the body but when I see it it didn't appear. I think that the theme Accelerate has a code that has a fixed white image, How is this?

Comment: Can I atleast know why my question got a downvote?

Comment: No idea about the downvote, but I would be surprised that the Appearance settings does not work for you given the theme is part of the WP Repository.  Have you actually tried setting the background and/or colour using this method instead of introducing your own CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their may be background image or no back ground image in wordpress according to the theme you are currently working with. Anyway you can add background image inside the body of a page in wordpress by the following ways :
Select css class from "main.css" located wp-contents/themes/your-current-theme/css/main.css, inside css edit "body" as

```
body{
/*...propeties..*/
background-image:url(back-img-url);
}
```

if it overridden by default images of your theme can use this instead of above

```
body{
/*...propeties..*/
background-image:url(back-img-url) !important;
}
```

In case you are using a custom template inside wordpress find the body class from the css you are using and change this as above.or using image inside page with img tag then make direct changes for this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by clicking Theme Options -> Design and choose the "Boxed Layout" instead of Wide Layout